# Coordinator Layout View prevents other layouts from being displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` used for displaying an `AppBarLayout`. However, the issue is that my `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` are hidden by my `ListView`. Moreover, my `ListView` does not show fully: rather, part of the first `ListView` element is cut off but I can scroll through and see the rest. Below was my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        android:id="@+id/view_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:background="#e6e6e6">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
            fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_status" />

    </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
                android:layout_below="@id/view_post">
            </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One thing I don't understand is why when I click on the `design` tab of my layout, it just seems like all my layouts overlap each other as opposed to displaying below each other. Furthermore, I don't see why the `ListView` is prioritized being shown over my `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. Is there any way I can get it so that I have the following structure from top to bottom: `AppBarLayout` -> `RelativeLayout` -> `ListView` -> `LinearLayout`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

If it means anything, in my AndroidManifest, I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

> Block quote

EDIT: this is an example of what I want to achieve[image: example]

Edit: After taking some advice from tiny sunshine, here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        android:id="@+id/view_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:background="#e6e6e6">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
            fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_status" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
            android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/send_message">
        </ListView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: Issue with `EditText`. As you can see, the layout only shows the `ListView` when I click the `EditText` and hides everything including the `ActionToolBar` and `Status Bar`.

[image: Issue with <code>EditText</code>]

Edit: Showing Android Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".com.tabs.activity.Comments"
        android:label="View Post"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".com.tabs.activity.news_feed"/>
    </activity>
```

Edit: Suggestion by Tiny Sunlight:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <ToolBar></ToolBar>
  <Relative Layout as List header></RelativeLayout as ListHeader>
  <ListView></ListView>
  <LinearLayout for Edit Text></LinearLayout for EditText>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Plz upload the image you want to achieve.

Comment: Added an image of what I want!

Comment: just add marginTop = RelativeLayout's height and marginBotton = LinearLayout' height and ListView's height should be set to match_parent . If you don't need animation , plz remove CoordinatorLayout AppBarLayout and  contain all view in a RelativeLayout.Do you need animation like when you scroll up Listview ,RelativeLayout'height change to zero ?

Comment: @tinysunlight I don't need Animation but I am just wondering then, how can I achieve a the toolbar look that I posted in the image above without Coordinator Layout? I thought that's the only way I can do that.

Comment: I added a answer. Toolbar is just a View .It has nothing t o do with Coordinator Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a ScrollView and set softInputMode to adjustResize.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/comments_appbar"
            android:id="@+id/view_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:background="#e6e6e6">

            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_status" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_post">
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If I replace the `Coordinator Layout` with `RelativeLayout` my Android status bar is all white but everything else seems to work. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I can see my status bar as the correct color only when I use the Coordinator Layout, but not when I use the RelativeLayout. I wonder why this is happening. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I actually got it all to work interestingly enough, but now whenever I click my `EditText`, the only part you can visibly see is the `ListView` but you can't see the `RelativeLayout` with the id `view_post`. I have posted my code up above to show what changes I've made. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` . If you could help me out that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Plz update screenshot when soft keyboard show And AndroidManifest.

Comment: Hi, I have updated screenshot. What would you want to see regarding the `AndroidManifest` ? I don't think it would help much. I've included the `activity` tag in the above post.

Comment: I tried wrapping my first `Relative Layout` in a `ScrollView` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just add a ScrollView and set softInputMode to adjustResize.

Comment: Hi, I just can't have a `ListView` with a `ScrollView` as a parent. Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: 1.use framelayout as prarent 2.add toobar 3.add view above list as listheader 4.add list with header .5 add view about input. 6. set marginTop of headerlist  to toobar's hight , margin bottom to  inputview's hight. 7.set softInputMode to adjust resize.

Comment: How would you perform 3 and 4? I am a little new to android programming. Would it be something like this? I have posted my attempt above

Comment: Just try to search listview addHeaderView.I'm working.